# Laravel | Data is not saved in database when inserting in Controller

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am new to Laravell, and my first task is to insert invoice data into the database. Unluckily I don't get a exception message or anything simliar so I don't know where to begin searching.
The model down below holds information of a invoice

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateInvoiceTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('invoice', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->double('priceNet');
            $table->double('priceGross');
            $table->double('vat');
            $table->string('userClearing')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('clearingDate')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('invoice');
    }
}
```

Below is the insert function in my InvoiceController, which should be called.
Like in the tutorial, I create a new object and save it to the database.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $invoice = new Invoice();
        $invoice->id = $post->id;
        $invoice->name = $request->input('name');
        $invoice->vat = $request->input('vat');
        $invoice->priceNet = $request->input('priceNet');
        $invoice->priceGross = $request->input('priceGross');
            //$invoice->userClearing = $request->input('userClearing');
            //$invoice->clearingDate = $request->clearingDate;
        //$invoice->created_at = Carbon\Carbon::now(); //$request->created_at;
        //$invoice->modified_at = Carbon\Carbon::now(); //$request->modified_at;
        
        $invoice->save();
        return view('list-invoice');
    }
```

Below is the code for my view, where i have the input fields, for the data and a button to save the data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            @if( isset($invoice)) 
                <title> Update Invoice </title>
            @endif 
            @if( !isset($invoice)) 
                <title> Insert Invoice </title>
            @endif 
      
        <!-- Styles -->
     
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
      
      @if( isset($invoice)) 
                <h1> Update Invoice </h1>
            @endif 
            @if( !isset($invoice)) 
                <h1> Insert Invoice </h1>
            @endif 
      
      <form action="{{ isset($invoice) ? route('invoice.update', [$invoice->id]) : route('invoice.store') }}" method=" {{ isset($invoice) ? 'PUT' : 'POST' }} "> 
          <table>
          
          @if(isset($invoice))
                <tr>
                    <td> ID </td>
                    <td> <input name="id" type="text"> {{isset($invoice) ? $invoice->id : ""}} </input> </td>
                </tr>
          @endif    
                
                <tr>
                    <td> Name </td>
                    <td> <input name="name" type="text"> {{ isset($invoice) ? $invoice->name : "" }} </input> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td> priceNet </td>
                    <td> <input name="priceNet" type="text"> {{isset($invoice) ? $invoice->priceNet : ""}} </input> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td> priceGross </td>
                    <td> <input name="priceGross" type="text"> {{isset($invoice) ? $invoice->priceGross : ""}} </input> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td> vat </td>
                    <td> <input name="vat" type="text"> {{isset($invoice) ? $invoice->vat : ""}} </input> </td>
                </tr>   
                
          </table>
          @if (isset($invoice))
            <button type="submit"> Save changes to invoice </button>
          @endif
          @if(!isset($invoice))
            <button type="submit"> Insert as new invoice </button> 
          @endif
          
          
          <button> Zurück zu Invoice Liste </button>
      </form>
      
      
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know if it is important, but here is my web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/test',function(){
    return 'Hello World!';
});

Route::post('/invoice/insert', 'app\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController@store');

Route::resource('/invoice', InvoiceController::class);
```

Comment: `$post` is undefined in `$post->id`. Or this is not the real code or you don't have errors enabled.

Comment: When you have defined `$table->id()` (auto incrementing column) in the migration, you don't need to set the `id` manually. You can fill all other columns except id and save. The `id` column will be populated at database level automatically. Also check if you have mass assignment protection on the columns you are trying to fill they will not be persisted. So you must either have `$fillable` array containing all columns which you want to fill data or have `$guarded` without column names for which you want to fill data. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

Have you define these columns in your Model fileable[] array

```
$fileable[]
```